# Is a bachelor in Computer Science Engineering a viable idea if my ultimate objective is to be a mathematical modelling engineer?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, engineering

I want to mathematically model reality and use these models to solve problems. Will a degree in Computer Science Engineering allow me to do this?

**Additional background**. Reading the overview of a master's graduate degree (MSC to be exact) in modelling mechanical engineer, it really spiked my interest. I am not a mathematical genius though, and I need to at least see applications and more or less concrete problems/implementations. Also relevant could be that I am a senior in high school and I learned programming all by myself.

**Systems I would find interesting to get to know better by creating mathematical models**

I am most interested in physics and general mathematical patterns, like the approach found in *Albert-László Barabási*'s book *Network Science*. 
I am not interested in specializing in any particular field just because of the field itself.

Comment: I couldn't really understand the question and I've edited in an attempt to make it clearer. (OP: Please edit further if necessary.)

Comment: I don't know what a mathematical modeling engineer is, but "modeling reality using mathematics" sounds like graphics programming / computer vision (which is a subfield of CS) might be for you.

Comment: I mean mathematical modelling

Comment: @user7474 I didn't mean the spelling, but the concept behind it.

Comment: Of course, me too 
I meant not visual modeling/modelling I really don't know, but mathematical representation/approach

Comment: @user7474 Adding some concrete examples of what you want to model might be useful. E.g., biological systems, civil engineering systems, ...

Comment: J.Ari made a good point for you when you asked the same question here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18937/10902

Comment: Yes, I found that constructive as well, but I am not sure I am up for that much of raw mathematics for that long a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my own experience, Im doing PhD in computer graphics, mainly physics simulation, and I have a master in mathematics, the program was called "mathematical modeling" it was mainly analysis, partial differential equations, numerical analysis and continuum mechanics.

Physics simulation is nothing else then solving partial differential equations and I can see that a math background is much more useful then computer science background when I look at my peers.

So I would recomend a math degree with a focus on numerics and physics.

---

**edit**: I see that you are a little bit worried to study math, that it might be way too much math for your taste. However, you are in a great position because you have a great motivation to study mathematics. You can always come up with things to model with math you are being thaught at school. From using projective spaces in computer graphics to fourier analysis in image processing . BUT remember one think. Do not expect that profesors will motivate you(it is a bonus if they do) but you have to activelly look for things that motivate you, everyone gets excited by different things.

Comment: Another point to consider is that the kind of math that a computer scientist needs is very different from the one a mathematical modeling expert uses. CS people mostly want discrete mathematics (combinatorics, some number theory, sequences, ...), modelers need continuous mathematics (differential equations, function spaces...).

Comment: @tom, thank you for your detailed answer and also for adding an edit, I find them really useful. I know I can't expect my professors to motivate me, and I do want to participate in projects and researches related to my interests

Comment: @FedericoPoloni yes, that is one thing I myself have been wondering about, and I know I have to take that into consideration. I think I want both, at least for the time being.